# Access: Text , Memo or VarChar ? Which one to use?

Tags: ms-access, types

What's the difference between VarChar, Text and Memo in Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-differences-between-data-types-in-an-access-database-and-access-project-HP005274573.aspx?CTT=1)

- Access Text is equivalent to sql server VARCHAR
- Access Memo is equivalent to sql server TEXT

Comment: Does access have a VARCHAR type? I thought that was just in SQL server. You can have Unicode fields in access but they don’t have their own type like NVARCHAR –v- VARCHAR. Other than that I cant add to the answer renick gave

Comment: yep I can do this in Microsoft Access : 

ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ALTER COLUMN MYCOLUMN VARCHAR(255)

Answer (score 0):

How can be ACCESS : MEMO is equivalent to while MEMO is UNICODE in Access while VARCHAR in SQL SERVER is Non-Unicoe

Each byte is 1 byte in varchar , but in MEMO it is 2 bytes

The EQUIVALENT datatype for MEMO is NVARCHAR in sql server.